# libgdx progressbar not showing up on main screen

Tags: java, libgdx, progress-bar

I am trying to create a Progress Bar that will be updated as the player moves. For now I am just trying to get the Progress bar to show up on the screen. I can't seem to figure out why it's not appearing
on the screen. The player sprites show, but not the progress bar. Tia!

Here is the Stamina Bar class which uses the Progress Bar:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Widget;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;

public class StaminaBar extends Widget implements Updatable { 

    public ProgressBar pb;
    public Texture progress_bar = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/pb.jpg"));
    public Texture pb_knob = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/bat_knob.jpg"));
    public ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle pbs = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle(); 



    public StaminaBar(){


    pbs.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(progress_bar));
        pbs.knob = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(pb_knob));

        pb = new ProgressBar(0f, 60f, 3f, true, pbs);
        pb.setValue(58);
        pb.setPosition(0, 0);
        pb.setVisible(true);
        pb.setSize(40f, 100f);
        pb.validate();


    }


    @Override 
    public void update(float d){


    }


}
```

Here is the Renderer class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Widget;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;

import edu.groupa.gameobjects.GameObject;
import edu.groupa.gameobjects.StaminaBar;


public class Renderer {

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Controller control;


    //Texture bg1;
    //private float bg1Xpos;

    public Renderer(Controller c){
        control = c;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    }
    public void render(){

        StaminaBar st = new StaminaBar();


        spriteBatch.begin();

        // Call all the draws of the individual objects here
        for(GameObject gObj : control.getDrawableObjects()){
            gObj.sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        spriteBatch.end();

    }
```

Comment: in the end I needed to declare a Stage object from the Stage class and then add the ProgressBar to the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because you don't draw it. You declare it in render, which you should do in Create. 
I managed to get the progressbar to work, but then I used a stage, added it to it and draw the stage. You will have to add it to the batch.